# EF Core dynamically ignoring column

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

Below I'm trying to dynamically ignore a column in the database based on an attribute being set in the entity class.  I can't work out what to put for ?????.  I tried prop but no good.  Please help.

```
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MyTable).GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                foreach (object attr in attrs)
                {
                    DatabaseAttribute dbAttr = attr as DatabaseAttribute;
                    if (dbAttr != null)
                    {
                        string propName = prop.Name;
                        System.Version minVersion = new System.Version(dbAttr.MinVersion);
                        if (databaseVersion < minVersion)
                        {
                            // The database doesn't know about this property, ignore it
                            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Ignore(d => ?????);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Ignore(prop.Name);
```

Or you can build the expression dynamically

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Ignore(Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTable)),prop));
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that.  I hadn't noticed the different options for Ignore.  Cheers.